# JavaScript: animate list item sequentially one at a time repeatedly

Tags: javascript, html, css, settimeout, setinterval

I am trying to animate a list item sequentially one at a time repeatedly. Where I have a list containing some list items. What I want to do is use javascript to animate each list item one at a time. I also have to remove the animation from the previous item when it animates the next one. The problem is I am not used to setIntervals or setTimeout functions. I am a beginner in javascript.

```js
  const ThumbnailSlider = document.querySelectorAll('.thumbnail-slider li');

    setInterval(() => {
      ThumbnailSlider.forEach( (item, i) => {
      const ms = (i+1) * 2000;
      setTimeout(() => {
        item.classList.add('active')
      }, ms);
    });
    }, 2000);
```

```css
  .thumbnail-slider {
     position: relative;
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
     }
    .thumbnail-slider li {
     position: relative;
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
     }
     .thumbnail-slider li.active {
     background: cyan;
     }
```

```html
    <ul class="thumbnail-slider">
            <li>list item one</li>
            <li>list item two</li>
    </ul>
```

I know this javascript is not enough as I am not removing the active class anywhere using .classList.remove.I also know about toggle.

Comment: setTimeout & setInterval are async funcs. For example `item.classList.add('active')` , item is undefined for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like below :-

`setTimeout` alone should suffice. We will **add** new class to **current element** and **remove** the class for the **previous element**.

```js
const ThumbnailSlider = document.querySelectorAll('.thumbnail-slider li');

let previousItem;
function animate(){
  ThumbnailSlider.forEach( (item, i) => {
  const ms = (i+1) * 2000;
  setTimeout(() => {
    previousItem?.classList.remove('active');
    item.classList.add('active')
    previousItem = item;
    if(i===ThumbnailSlider.length-1){
    animate();
    }
  }, ms);
});
}

animate();
```

```css
.thumbnail-slider {
 position: relative;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 }
.thumbnail-slider li {
 position: relative;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 }
 .thumbnail-slider li.active {
 background: cyan;
 }
```

```html
<ul class="thumbnail-slider">
        <li>list item one</li>
        <li>list item two</li>
        <li>list item third</li>
        <li>list item fourth</li>
        <li>list item fifth</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: wow, that was quick. thankyou! But if I want to do this repeatedly? I will have to use setInterval right? because this is just one-time animation. I want  this to happen infinitly.

Comment: You can do it via recursion. Updated in the answer. There is a possible answer with `setInterval` too I think.

Comment: It's working! Thanks. I learned a lot from this.